# How to compute gradients to fool an image classifier?

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow

I am trying to get the standard trick-an-image-classifier example working in `TensorFlow`.

(That is, adjust the input image by following the gradient so it is misclassified, e.g., https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/five/why-do-neural-networks-think-a-panda-is-a-vulture .)

I have downloaded the inception-v3 model from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html , and have it working to classify images.

But I am having a hard time computing the gradients to adjust the input image.  I was hoping I could get some help as to how it works in `TensorFlow`.

This is the basic idea for what I have been trying:

```
with tf.Session() as sess: 
  feed_dict = {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data}
  softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
    # at this point, sess.run(softmax_tensor, feed_dict) works...
  input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('DecodeJpeg/contents:0')
  grad = tf.gradients(softmax_tensor, input_tensor)[0]
  real_grad = grad.eval(feed_dict)
```

Even though `sess.run()` works as it should, `tf.gradients()` is just returning [None].  This is obviously a very beginner question, but can anyone point me toward where I am going wrong here?  Why isn't gradients doing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `tf.gradients()` returns `[None]` is that `input_tensor` is subjected to a non-differentiable transformation (i.e., JPEG decoding and a cast) before it is fed into the Inception network.  Instead, you should operate on the **result** of the JPEG decoding (**EDIT:** and cast), as follows:

```
# This tensor is the result of the DecodeJpeg op.
decoded_input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Cast:0')

grad = tf.gradients(softmax_tensor, decoded_input_tensor)[0]

real_grad = grad.eval(feed_dict)
```

After you have generated your image that tricks the classifier, you can use the [`tf.image.encode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/image.html#encode_jpeg) op to transform it back into a JPEG image.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, and indeed this seems to work (at least if I start with 'Cast:0' instead of 'DecodeJpeg:0').  I don't have everything working yet, but I'll update my question with a full explanation when I do.

Comment: Thanks—update the answer to make the `'Cast:0'` fix.

Comment: @mrry, Maybe you can help also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169827/tensorflow-gradients-returns-none ? Seems that it is related.